# Send email with ajax and jquery in wordpress template

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm tryng to develop a simple template for wordpress and I put in the footer a contact form so i build this code

```
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send-mail.php",
            data: "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&message=" + message,
            cache: false,
            success: function(){ alert("this is a test"); }
        });
```

but it doesn't work.

I'm in doubt about where to place the file "send-mail.php", in the template directory or in the root? I think the first one but safety is never enough :D

there's anyone that can help me?

Comment: The relative path you're using points to the directory that the running javascript file is located in. If this is "not working" you must be getting an error message.

Comment: This may not be constructive but I'm sure that Wordpress has this functionality built in. [see here](http://www.wp-themix.org/wordpress/how-to-add-a-jquery-ajax-contact-form-to-wordpress/)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to use this:-

[For ajax related stuff](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_ajax_%28action%29)

[For email related stuff](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_mail)

Comment: Use proper indentation and use hyperlink before posting any link.